# $\{(x,y)\in X\times\Bbb{R}|0\le y\le f(x)\}\in \mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{B}_\Bbb{R}$ implies $f$ measurable

Tags: measure-theory

> **Exercise**. Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f\colon X\to[0,+\infty)$ any function. Show that if $$R(f,X):=\{(x,y)\in X\times\Bbb{R}|0\le y\le f(x)\}\in \mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{B}_\Bbb{R},$$ then $f$ is measurable.

I was trying to show that for any real number $a>0$ the set $f^{-1}([a,+\infty))$ belongs to $\mathcal{M}$ (since  for $a\le 0$, $f^{-1}([a,+\infty))=X\in\mathcal{M}$).

**Remark**. Here I'm usying "$f$ is measurable $\Longleftrightarrow$ $f^{-1}([a,+\infty)\in\mathcal{M}$".

For next, the idea is show that $f^{-1}([a,+\infty))\times\Bbb{R}\in\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{B}_\Bbb{R}$, because this implies via Theorem that for any $y\in\Bbb{R}$ $$f^{-1}([a,+\infty))=(f^{-1}([a,+\infty))\times\Bbb{R})^y\in\mathcal{M}.$$

But of course, I'm not so secure of what am I doing...
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe the solution is $\mathcal{M}\ni(\underbrace{R(f,X)}_{\in\mathcal{M}\otimes\mathcal{B}_\Bbb{R}})^a=f^{-1}([a,+\infty))$